# CURL error 28 while downloading Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Tags: laravel, curl, composer-php, packagist

I'm trying to install Yajra, a Laravel package to handle server-side works of DataTables jQuery Plugin via AJAX option. But I got this problem and I can't fix this. Please do you have anything to help me?

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while
> downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Connection timed
> out after 10000 milliseconds

Answer (score 6):

I remember i run this command

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

then CURL error 28 while downloading was resolved.

Comment: I used this with require and it fixed it. 
composer require 'drupal/project-name' --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: not helps :( error still happens:
Failed to download doctrine/inflector from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/inflector/zipball/f9301a5b2fb1216b2b08f02ba04dc45423db6bff: SSL connection timeout
    Now trying to download from source

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be caused by *DNS* issue, try To Flush the *DNS Cache* by running this command `ipconfig /flushdns` *if you are using **Windows***.

Comment: Using WSL2 and Ubuntu in Windows, I encountered the error described in the question. I opened another Windows Terminal and ran ipconfig /flushdns.
I then returned to the Ubuntu window and repeated. No error. I'm upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this error, when I was trying to build a Laravel app with docker, was to change the MTU on the network configuration of the docker container. This depends on the MTU configuration that the host has, in our case was 1400.
We had to apply this configuration for the network on the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
networks:
  my-net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1400
```

As suggested in this article: [Docker MTU Configuration](https://help.nordlayer.com/docs/docker-mtu-configuration)

And then applied this network to all images in the file like this:

```
MySQL:
  image: mariadb:10.11
  networks:
    - my-net
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the issue happened when I was hotspotting, once I moved to a Wifi network it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pls consider that future readers of the question will be trying to compare their problem with the information you provided. So, type of network (5G? LTE?), and the hotspot (were you in "Low Data" mode on an iPhone), etc. will help out future readers.