# PHP composer diagnose curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Operation timed out

Tags: php, http, curl, composer-php, timeout

I think this question is duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71741993/curl-error-28-while-downloading-connection-timed-out-after-10000-milliseconds) and I tried suggestions on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722036/curl-error-60-while-downloading-https-repo-packagist-org-certificate-issue-on?rq=2) but not working with me so I want to know how to diagnose the issue so I can resolve the problem.

The following image is the important part of the output of `composer diagnose` command which indicates that the https connectivity to packagist is failed

```
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Operation timed out after 10006 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

and Checking github.com oauth access failed alse

```
Checking github.com oauth access: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while downloading https://api.github.com/: Operation timed out after 10003 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Information might help:
Operating System: windows 11
Composer version: 2.5.8
PHP version: 8.1.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022
cURL version: 7.77.0 libz 1.2.12 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1o
zip: extension present, unzip not available, 7-Zip not available

[image]

This is the full output of `composer diagnose`

```
>composer diag
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK git version 2.33.0
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
Checking github.com oauth access: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while downloading https://api.github.com/: Operation timed out after 10008 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E5CD41 7EC7CCC5 573900D0  8717B9A6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC74567 ECE52265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions: Operation timed out after 10010 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
Composer version: 2.5.8
PHP version: 8.1.7
PHP binary path: A:\SwadiServer\php-8.1.7\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022
cURL version: 7.77.0 libz 1.2.12 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1o
zip: extension present, unzip not available, 7-Zip not available
```

I don't know what is the reason of the problem how to check if there is an port block by ISP  because when I visit https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json on the browse it opened and on the terminal it has an issue with curl error timeout.
When I use the command `curl https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json` it output the content of JSON as following:

```
{"packages":[],"notify-batch":"https://packagist.org/downloads/","providers-url":"/p/%package%$%hash%.json","metadata-url":"/p2/%package%.json","metadata-changes-url":"https://packagist.org/metadata/changes.json","search":"https://packagist.org/search.json?q=%query%&type=%type%","list":"https://packagist.org/packages/list.json","security-advisories":{"metadata":true,"api-url":"https://packagist.org/api/security-advisories/","query-all":true},"providers-api":"https://packagist.org/providers/%package%.json","warning":"Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/","warning-versions":"<1.99","info":"\u001b[37;44m#StandWith\u001b[30;43mUkraine\u001b[0m","provider-includes":{"p/provider-2013$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"8a29694e049e55d59398175f9865f74f814ef6f18561df7e4ed55d481bbffd55"},"p/provider-2014$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"983d741575411519a50469cf97ecd9b5daa03e2245ed5f2a95898f09ee14a4f6"},"p/provider-2015$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"80669bcdad1c7dfda950435f379143cec432e1f39ac6fa241bd15b9a314c18bf"},"p/provider-2016$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"0d91a5b10638c17953b7cbd01764a5777c8cc2a9d6ea9553cb9998b8f859decf"},"p/provider-2017$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"3260903a1f98b9093d06f5853cee88d2249785f913f215ce05c9d9137305ba88"},"p/provider-2018$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"213f8d51c38388a03b26a80bc26c30f192404d9777b8d67bc2305e1c63ed6c90"},"p/provider-2019$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"552a5f20f18cca366842851479fc2e3329a25797331af83ec5518c9b83f6c85d"},"p/provider-2020$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"1ce0786e752e10f63a1e6ce018eee9b3b97abcd23b759602fccce070adb446e3"},"p/provider-2021$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"a4fd371d659d3d7dfb9157bfc393ab2bd3a4a7a415d04b9a70b242e8c738d215"},"p/provider-2022$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"3d68b79ac7d2667a630b33fdcb02c29ec1085a41d63666072800e57848696115"},"p/provider-2022-10$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"194382abede763175257fd087eb2559c8aa76a4796ae9f87cc23d623c650eb2b"},"p/provider-2023-01$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"cab48a65d3b469e2f632656ef6c08e2db89f0c4963e57276d57427920a24cb07"},"p/provider-2023-04$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"6397a519b15160650aeb03eec8dc812b783ef2b60db9e9a36073073b0fa96d96"},"p/provider-2023-07$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"bf34a702a973364de3c08af910d954dc6c211861e7079d5755dcfb13e8639e2a"},"p/provider-archived$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"16aaa74e1529959dda7a45618413ac5144668fcbb5c367eabf52089e71e5bf18"},"p/provider-latest$%hash%.json":{"sha256":"148e7b9ddce4a1550e3fb031e7884eff80627c226cdadae15878c2e068fd772d"}}}
```

Comment: This looks like a networking problem. In your network secure connections are blocked. I'd give it a try with upgrading the PHP version 8.1.7 is a bit dated (8.1.22 is current), _maybe_ it helps, otherwise could it be that you are in a restricted network, especially for Wide Area Network (WAN), a.k.a. the interwebs? Seek out assistance from your responsible network administration.

Comment: I used multiple versions of php (8.1 , 8.0 , 7.4 , 7.3 ) and it dose not working.

```sh
Administrator@Kudos MINGW64 /c/tmp
$ php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel hi
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./hi"

In CurlDownloader.php line 365:

  curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: O
  peration timed out after 10010 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--p
refer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] ...
```